# trouble writing the output of script to a file

Tags: python

I'm a beginner, just learning Python, but decided to take a break from that to explore some libraries and scripts. I quickly determined that Python might be perfect for automating my search for a new place to live. Anyway,the script writes nice HTML to stdout but I'm struggling to write to a file so I can review the output in a browser.

Here's the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs4

url_base = 'http://eugene.craigslist.org/search/apa'
params = dict(bedrooms=2, housing_type=6)
rsp = requests.get(url_base, params=params)
print(rsp.url)
print(rsp.text[:500])

html = bs4(rsp.text, 'html.parser')

print(html.prettify()[:1000])



dwellings = html.find_all('p', attrs={'class': 'row'})
print(len(dwellings))

this_dwelling = dwellings[15]
print(this_dwelling.prettify())
```

I've looked at this but it's unclear what specifically I'd put in the write() to write the script output to the file.

```
f = open('house.html','w')
f.write('What goes here?')
f.close()
```

So then I tried both file redirectionand piping to tee, returning this error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./house.py", line 10, in 
    print(rsp.text[:500])
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\ufeff' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)

Maybe I should have stayed with my introductory Hello World exercises and and stayed in the learning sequence but now I'm frustrated and want to get this script working first. Overall, Python is a lot of fun to work with.

Comment: You can think of `f.write` doing exactly the same as `print` - but then to a file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try writing the dwellings to the file instead of printing it to the screen like this.

```
f = open('house.html','w')
f.write(this_dwelling.prettify())
f.close()
```

Put that at the end of your script to populate your HTML file with some of the results.

Comment: Thank you, Jim. I tried that and it didn't like 'this'.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./house.py", line 27, in <module>
    f.write(this.dwelling.prettify())
NameError: name 'this' is not defined

Comment: Hi Randy, I don't mean to be dense, but I don't see any changes to the answer.

Comment: Randy, you mean Rad's response about write replacing print? The suggestion there that each instance of print should be a write?

Comment: Hi marmot, I had accidentally used a . instead of _ in this_dwelling. So the code was looking for a this variable instead of this_dwelling.

Comment: Jim, that worked! Thank you. I really appreciate your patience.

Comment: Darn, I'm too new to add points to your answer. Sorry. I'll work on getting better at this so I can contribute something useful to this forum.

Comment: @Marmot: you do not need reputation to accept an answer.